# Is it safe to call multiple AsyncTasks within an AsyncTask and then stop the outer task if necessary?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

If I did something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private GetDataTask mGDT;   

    //onCreate() and onCreateView() are implied here

    public void runTasks()
    {
        new TaskOne().execute();
        new TaskTwo().execute();
        new TaskThree().execute();
    }

    public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            runTasks();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mGDT = new GetDataTask();
        mGDT.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        mGDT.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Would calling `mGDT.cancel(true)` in `onDestroy()` end the individual AsyncTasks running in `runTasks()`? What is the best way to achieve something like this? I have multiple bots that will be gathering data from the web and I want each one on its own thread and I need to be able to cancel all of them if the fragment or activity is destroyed. I'm new to Android programming and multithreading so I'm not familiar with the best ways to do this type of multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

That's complicated.`cancel()` interrupts the thread that's running (the thread that will run `doInBackgroundImpl()`). If the outer task's `doInBackgroundImpl()` hasn't run yet, it won't run. However, if it's already run or in the middle of running, it's going to run unless you explicitly look for the interrupted flag,

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        if (!Thread.isInterrupted()) {
          runTasks();
        }
    }
```

And of course if the code execution of the thread has already passed the conditional interrupted check, it's going to call `runTasks()`.

Now, if `runTasks()` does execute(), canceling the outer task won't effect the execution of the inner tasks. Once they are executed, they are placed on `AsyncTask`'s executor queue and will be executed when previous task is completed (or right away if the queue is empty).

Takeaways,

1) Each executed task is independent. There's no notion of a subthread or anything like that. You have to explicitly cancel each task. The fact that one task is started by another task has no bearing on the semantics of `cancel()`.

2) You simply can't stop a thread cold. It's why `Thread.stop()` is deprecated since Java 1.2 or something. All you can do is mark it interrupted, then either hope the code you use in the thread respects `isInterrupted()`, or write your own code to respect it.

In your case, if your goal is to cancel all subtasks when the parent task is canceled, you can do something like,

```
@Override
public void cancel(boolean interrupt) {
  super.cancel(interrupt);
  task1.cancel(interrupt);
  task2.cancel(interrupt);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand what you're saying, it is safe to do what I did, and it will end the individual threads when I call `cancel(true)` in onDestroy()? Also can you elaborate on your 2nd paragraph or at least point me to a good link that explains executeOnExecutor?

Comment: It depends on if `mGDT` has started the sub tasks (1, 2, 3). If code in mGDT that starts the tasks hasn't run, canceling mGDT will cancel the sub tasks (by nature of stopping them from being executed in the first place). If mGDT has already started the subtasks, canceling mGDT won't cancel them. Why don't you override cancel() in the outer task to call cancel in the subtasks?

Comment: re: `executeOnExecutor()`. Best thing is to read the API docs on `Executor` and look at the source code for `AsyncTask` to see how it uses them.

Comment: Thanks that helped, the only thing is I read in the documentation that AsyncTasks can only be called on the the UI thread, so calling`execute()` on all three tasks in `doInBackground()` would not work.

Comment: Well, the bigger question is why you need to execute a task from the background thread of a task. It's not a long running operation. I think you had it structured like that to try and streamline canceling the subtasks, but considering that's not going to work like you expect, you are better off just ditching the outer task.  You can keep your subtasks in a collection to ease canceling all of them when you need.